# System Characterization: multiply imaginary component by scalar

Tags: discrete-signals, continuous-signals, linear-systems, complex

I tried solving a test question that frankly stumped me. If you could explain to me the solution I’d be really grateful.

> Given $a, b \in \mathcal{R}$ the system $R_v$ takes the complex input $a + bj$ and returns $a + bvj$. For which values of v the system is linear?

This system accepts both discrete and continuous inputs.

The answer is $v=1$, but I don’t understand why for any other $v$ linearity is not fulfilled. It even seemed trivial to me that it is.
Like if I take take two complex inputs I can characterize as $x_1 = a(t) + b(t)j$ and $x_2 = c(t) + d(t)j$ applying the system: 
  would result in $$\psi\{\alpha x_1+ \beta x_2\} = (\alpha a+\beta c)(t) + (\alpha b+ \beta d)vj$$, whereas applying the system to each one separately would do the same thing: $$ \psi\{\alpha x_1 \} + \psi \{\beta x_2  \} = (\alpha a + \alpha bvj) + (\beta c + \beta dvj)  $$
so I think I must be missing something here

Comment: please focus on one question per question post :) That honestly makes things easier! Adding a bit on your own attempts will help. For system1, that would entail you trying with a $v\ne1$ and proving linearity – then we actually have a question that doesn't boil down to doing what this homework wants *you* to do. (also, I assume "the complex input", which you don't mention is some $z = a + jb$? You will need to spell that out for us.)

Comment: (because these are independent problems, I just removed the second one – you can still find the original markdown in the edit history. Feel free to ask a separate question post about that system

Comment: that’s reasonable - these problems appeared on a past test as a part of the same question - I understand the separation though - i agree.  i have their solutions but the solutions are brief and I’m struggling with understanding them.

Comment: Show the case specifically with $v\ne1$ using your proof of linearity. For example a linear system with $a+jb$ in and produces $a+j5b$ out.

Comment: @DanBoschen: Will the OP's proof fail in that case?

Comment: @MattL. The OP’s proof is linearity for a mythical linear system that would produce a gain on the imaginary component only. Still we need to show a case of a system ithat can do that, if that exists.  Then that system too can follow the rules of linearity as shown

Comment: @DanBoschen: Interestingly the systems passes the formal linearity test with flying colors for $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{R}$. It only fails ones you allow $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{C}$. Which begs the question: what is the formal linearity test for a system with complex inputs and outputs, i.e.  $\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C} $

Comment: @Hilmar I am still not following; I am trying to think of the example linear system that would produce $\alpha +j v\beta $ with $\alpha + j\beta$ in, for real $v \ne 1$. Do you have one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem here is that the system has complex inputs and outputs and you would have to extend the definition of linear to complex scale factors. Assuming that $F(a+jb) = a+jvb$, $y = F(x)$ you would have to proof that

$$F(\alpha x_1 + \beta x_2) = \alpha F(x_1) + \beta F(x_2)$$

You have successfully proven that this is the case if the scale coefficients are real ($\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{R}$). However, for a complex system this must also hold for complex scale coefficients ($\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{C}$) which is indeed not the case here.

The answer $v=1$ is trivial since the system just turns into an identity.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the test for linearity suggests that the system is linear ***if*** we only consider real valued scale factors shows that the system would be linear if viewed as a ***real-valued*** multiple-input multiple-output (MIMO) system. We could model the system as one with two inputs and two outputs. In that case, the transfer function matrix is just a constant diagonal matrix:

$$\mathbf{H}=\left[\begin{array}{ll}1 & 0 \\ 0 & v\end{array}\right]\tag{1}$$

However, if viewed as a single-input single-output complex-valued system - as implied in the test question - , the system is not linear because the linearity test fails if we consider complex-valued scale factors. This is correctly pointed out in [Hilmar's answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/86618/4298).

I'd like to show another way to see that the given complex-valued system is not linear. First, note that the given system is cleary time-invariant. Consequently, if it were linear, it would need to be a linear time-invariant (LTI) system, and as such its output must be computable from its input via convolution with a (complex-valued) impulse response

$$h(t)=h_R(t)+jh_I(t)$$

With $x(t)=x_R(t)+jx_I(t)$ being the complex-valued input, the corresponding output is

$$y(t)=(x_R\star h_R)(t)-(x_I\star h_I)(t)+j\big[(x_R\star h_I)(t)+(x_I\star h_R)(t)\big]\tag{2}$$

From the specification of the system, we require the output to be

$$y(t)=x_R(t)+jvx_I(t)\tag{3}$$

Comparing $(2)$ with $(3)$ shows that there exists no impulse response $h(t)$ satisfying $(3)$. Hence, the system cannot be linear.

A complex-valued system can be viewed as a MIMO system. However, the transfer function matrix is very specific, and we can't choose the matrix entries independently. The transfer function matrix of a complex-valued system has the form

$$\mathbf{H}=\left[\begin{array}{ll}H_R(s) & -H_I(s) \\ H_I(s) & H_R(s)\end{array}\right]\tag{4}$$

where $H_R(s)$ and $H_I(s)$ are the transfer functions of the real and imaginary parts of the impulse response. Comparing $(4)$ with $(1)$ shows again that the given system cannot be implemented by a linear complex-valued system.